# How can I chain a map generating a tuple with a filter, in Scala?

Tags: function, scala, dictionary

So, I have a simple collection, say:

```
val a = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I want to map it to a list of tuples, and then filter over that, and then later map over the result of it, so it would be something like:

```
a.map(x => (x, x * x)).filter(tup => tup._2 < 10).map(tup => tup._1 + tup._2)
```

Except instead of using `tup` and `tup._1`, I want to use variable names like `number` and `square`, preferably in the arguments section.

Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider using partial function and collect function:

```
scala> val a = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> a.map(x => (x, x * x)) collect {
     |   case (number, square) if square < 10 =>
     |     number + square
     | }
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 6, 12)
```

Collect in this case works like a combination of map and filter